# Asynchronous Method Chaining

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise

I'm trying to achieve a chaining of the same `asynchronous` method. Basically what I want to do is just call `animation.animate({}).animate({})`. The second animate method needs to be called once the first one is completed.

Here is what I did, I think it's close but I can't still find how to make it work.

```
class Animation {

    constructor() {
        this.queue = new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {resolve()})
    }  

    animate(params) {
        this.queue.then(() => {
            return this.cssAnimate(params);
        })
        return this;
    }

    cssAnimate(params) {
        return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        //do stuff to animate

        params.el.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {resolve()})
        })
    }

}

let animation = new Animation();

animation
    .animate({}) 
    .animate({})
```

Comment: What is/isn't happening that you aren't/are expecting ?

Comment: What part is not working? I think the key is to make sure `resolve()` is called in `cssAnimate()` only when you are sure the animation is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reassign `this.queue` with a new Promise you get from 'this.queue.then'

```js
class Animation {

  constructor() {
    this.queue = Promise.resolve()
  }  

  animate(params) {
    this.queue = this.queue.then(() => this.cssAnimate(params))
    return this;
  }

  cssAnimate(params) {
    const {el, clz} = params
    
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      el.addEventListener('transitionend', resolve)
      el.classList.toggle(clz)
    })
  }
}


document.querySelector('#play').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let animation = new Animation();
  const el = document.querySelector('.box')

  animation
    .animate({
      el,
      clz: 'left'
    }) 
    .animate({
      el,
      clz: 'left'
    })
})
```

```css
.box {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 0;  
  transition: all 3s linear;
}

.left {
  
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<button id="play">Play</div>
```

Comment: Perfect that's exactly what I wanted to do thank you :)